# How to use built in methods in Golang?

Tags: go

I am trying this simple code:

```
var f1 float64 = 23.435
fmt.Println(f1.Acos())
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
f1.Acos undefined (type float64 has no field or method Acos)
```

Can anybody help me in understanding the right way of using the built in methods ?

Comment: First try to understand the language. You need to provide a float64 value to `math.Acos()` function. The correct way: `math.Acos(f1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Acos` is a function of the `math` package, not a built-in method of float64, so you must import it first

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)
```

Then, [as per documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Acos), you pass `f1` as an argument to the `math.Acos`

```
fmt.Println(math.Acos(f1))
```